# Unable to load flextable

Tags: r, flextable

It shows there is no package called 'flextable' even after installing the package.

```
install.packages("flextable")
library(flextable)
```

Comment: What was the output of `install.packages("flextable")`. Were there any errors that were displayed indicating why the package might not have been installed?

Comment: after installing the flextable package and then when i load it with library(flextable) it shows: there is no package called flextable.

Comment: I under stand that's the output when you run ` library(flextable)`, but what is the exact output you see when you run `install.packages("flextable")`? Is there a message that the package installed successfully? I would guess not. Most likely there is an error there.